# Adjoints of operators between different Hilbert spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

When we have an operator

$$
  T ~\colon \mathscr{H} \longrightarrow \mathscr{H}
$$

from a Hilbert space to itself, we can use the Riesz representation theorem to prove the existence of the adjoint map $T^*$ with the property

$$ 
  \langle Tx, y \rangle 
    = 
  \langle x, T^* y\rangle 
    \quad 
  \forall x, y \in \mathscr{H}
$$

However, if we instead have an operator

$$
  S ~\colon \mathscr{H_1} \longrightarrow \mathscr{H}_2
$$

between two different Hilbert spaces $\mathscr{H}_1$ and $ \mathscr{H}_2$, it is often sensible to talk about the map $S^*$ with the property

$$
  \langle Sx, y \rangle_{\mathscr{H}_2}
    =
  \langle x, S^* y \rangle_{\mathscr{H}_1}
    \quad
  \forall x \in \mathscr{H}_1, y \in \mathscr{H}_2
$$
In this case, it appears to me that we cannot use the Riesz representation theorem to prove the existence of $S^*$. This leads me to ask a few questions:

**Questions:**

- What hypotheses do we need for the operator $S^*$ to exist?
- How would we go about proving this existence?
- Where can I read about adjoints in this more general scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any continuous linear map $S:\mathscr{H}_1\to\mathscr{H}_2$ between two vector spaces we can define its transpose as $S^*:\mathscr{H}_2^*\to\mathscr{H}_1^*$ by letting $(S^*f)(x)=f(Sx)$ for any $x\in\mathscr{H}_1$ and $f\in\mathscr{H}_2^*$.
In order for $S^*f$ to belong to $\mathscr{H}_1^*$, the original map $S$ has to be continuous; otherwise we only get a map between the algebraic duals.

Hilbert spaces are naturally self-dual (by the Riesz representation theorem!), so we can think of $S^*$ as a map $S^*:\mathscr{H}_2\to\mathscr{H}_1$.
The dual pairing is (after identifying the spaces with their duals) the inner product, so the property $(S^*f)(x)=f(Sx)$ becomes $\langle S^*f,x\rangle_{\mathscr{H}_1}=\langle f,Sx\rangle_{\mathscr{H}_2}$.

The above discussion proves the existence of $S^*$ assuming continuity.
The construction becomes more complicated if $S$ is, say, discontinuous and defined only on a dense subspace.
Depending on your taste, things might look more transparent with a concrete operator on concrete spaces, such as the Laplacian on $L^2$, which is discontinuous, densely defined and self-adjoint.
In general $S^*$ is continuous if and only if $S$ is.

Comment: In this setting the dual space is the continuous dual space, i.e. the space of continuous linear functionals.
The construction of $S^*:\mathscr{H}_2^*\to\mathscr{H}_1^*$ depends on $S^*f$ actually being in $\mathscr{H}_1^*$ for any $f \in \mathscr{H}_2^*$.
It is not immediately clear to me that $S^*$ actually maps to **continuous** linear functionals of $\mathscr{H}_1$.
It seems that this is only true if $S$ is continuous.
This means that the construction **does** rely on $S$ being continuous.

Comment: @G.Bellaard Fair enough! I had overlooked that, but I updated the answer now.