# How to compute eigen values and eigen vectors for eigen value problem in terms of inner product?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

My apologies if this is a silly question. I feel like I'm misunderstanding something basic and just need a quick clarification.

I have an eigenvalue problem stated in terms of the inner product. More specifically, I have an operator $O: X \to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces. I would like to find the largest $n$ eigenvalues $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and corresponding $n$ eigenfunctions $\varphi_i \in X$ that satisfy $\langle O \varphi_i, Ov \rangle_Y = \lambda_i \langle \varphi_i, v \rangle_X$ for all $v \in X$. The $O \varphi_i$ for $i = 1,...n$ will span the space that I want to find.

I need to do this using the inner product matrices of $X$ and $Y$ (e.g for $X$ this means some matrix $I_X$ such that $\langle u, v \rangle_X = u^T I_X v$). My attempt so far is as follows

I think I can represent $\langle O \varphi_i, Ov \rangle_Y = \lambda_i \langle \varphi_i, v \rangle_X$ as

$M_{sol}^T I_Y M_{sol} = \lambda_i M_{input}^T I_X M_{input}$

where $M_{input}$ is a matrix whose columns are the basis functions in $X$ (basically the identity matrix) and $M_{sol}$ is a matrix whose $i^{th}$ column is a vector in $Y$ representing the value of the operator applied to the $i^{th}$ basis function, ie. $O(M_{input}(:,i))$.

So would this mean that I could find my eigenvalues by finding the eigenvalues of $M_{sol}^T I_Y M_{sol}$?

I feel weird about this because I feel I should be using $M_{input}^T I_X M_{input}$ somewhere in the calculations but I don't see how to connect it.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that $\varphi_i$ is an eigenfunction to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $O$? But this would mean $\langle O\varphi_i,Ov\rangle_Y=\lambda_i\langle\varphi_i,Ov\rangle_X$ and not what you wrote. What is $v$ anyway? Do you mean that the equation should hold for all $v\in X$?

Comment: Ok, so $\lambda_i$ and $\varphi_i$ are just a real number and an element of $X$ satisfying the condition. But what is $i$? Maybe the $\varphi_i$ should form a (orthonormal?) basis of $X$, but that is not clear from what you wrote. The part with $I_X$ and $I_Y$ is semi-clear to me. "I think I can represent...." has the big problem that $\varphi_i$ and $v$ are different things, but $M_{input}$ somehow represents them both. Finally, $M_{sol}^TI_YM_{sol}$ is a real number, not a matrix.

Comment: By the way, these questions aren't meant as criticism. Hope you're not discouraged.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you! No worries I really appreciate the feedback! I know my original post was a little vague. I'll fix up my post to answer your questions. Also good point on the vectors I think I have a fix for that as well I'll add it to the edit. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I now partially understand your question. Let me write it down in my words, and we'll see if that helps you.

It's possible that I have made a mistake somewhere, I didn't know the problem before.

---

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real Hilbert spaces and $O:X\rightarrow Y$ be a (continuous) linear operator. It should work similarly with complex Hilbert spaces, but you tagged real analysis, so maybe that's all you need.

You're looking for $\varphi\in X$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that
$$\langle O \varphi, Ov \rangle_Y = \lambda \langle \varphi, v \rangle_X$$
for all $v\in X$, and you're wondering whether this can be regarded as finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of some matrix or operator.

---

*High-level version*

Let us introduce the adjoint operator $O^*:Y\rightarrow X$ like [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122134/adjoints-of-operators-between-different-hilbert-spaces) Then our condition becomes
$$\left\langle O^*O\varphi,v\right\rangle_X=\lambda\langle\varphi,v\rangle_X$$
for all $v\in V$, or in other words
$$\left\langle O^*O\varphi,\cdot\right\rangle_X=\langle\lambda\varphi,\cdot\rangle_X.$$
Since $x\mapsto\langle x,\cdot\rangle_X$ is an isomorphism of $H$ onto the space $\mathcal{L}(X;\mathbb{R})$ of continuous linear functionals on $H$, this is equivalent to
$$O^*O\varphi=\lambda\varphi.$$
So the problem is finding the eigenvalues and -vectors of the operator $O^*O$.

---

*Low-level version with columns and matrices*

Let us assume that the underlying vector spaces of $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ for some $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, regard the elements of $X$ and $Y$ as columns. Also, define $I_X$ and $I_Y$ as in the question. Also, we can directly interpret $O$ as a matrix. This is probably the same as your $M_{sol}$, while $M_{input}$ is the unit matrix (not only basically).

Then the condition becomes
$$(O\varphi)^TI_Y(Ov)=\lambda\varphi^TI_Xv$$
for all $v\in X$, which is equivalent to
$$\varphi^TO^TI_YO=\lambda\varphi^TI_X,$$
and therefore, by transposing on both sides, to
$$O^TI_YO\varphi=\lambda I_X\varphi,$$
i.e.
$$I_X^{-1}O^TI_YO\varphi=\lambda\varphi.$$

So the problem is finding the eigenvalues and -vectors of the matrix $I_X^{-1}O^TI_YO$. This seems to be what you found out, but with the factor $I_X^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for writing this out! Seeing it written like this is very helpful. I greatly appreciate your input. My sincere apologies for the delayed response. 
This almost fully makes sense to me. My main question is that I think $I_x$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and $O$ and $I_y$ will be $m \times m$ matrices . So wouldn't this mean that the last line of multiplication doesn't fully work (unless $m=n$)?

Comment: @k12345 Glad I could help. :) It does work, because $O$ is not a square matrix, but an $m\times n$-matrix. Multiplying with $O$ on the left maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$, and multiplying with $O^T$ on the left maps $\mathbb{R}^m$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you very much for clearing that up for me!